# primitive calculator Second step,

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I try to get the code right for the minimum required steps to get to n and the subsequent list, steps are multiply by 2 or 3, or add 1. It should be implemented through dynamic programming since using greedy choices for this one is unsafe. First I got the minimum steps required using the following code, it works just fine .
What I can't get is how do I go about unpacking that list, please I don't need answers, this is an assignment for an online class, hints or Help is Ok, so I try to maintain my moral integrity here.

```
def optimal_sequence(n):
    sequence = [0]*(n+1)
    for i in range(2, n+1):
        if i % 3 == 0:
            sequence[i] = sequence[(i // 3)]+1
            if sequence[i] - sequence[i-1] <= 1:
                sequence[i] = sequence[i]
            else:
                sequence[i] = sequence[i-1] + 1
        elif i % 2 == 0:
            sequence[i] = sequence[(i // 2)]+1
            if sequence[i] - sequence[i-1] <= 1:
                sequence[i] = sequence[i]
            else:
                sequence[i] = sequence[i-1] + 1
        else:
            sequence[i] = sequence[i-1] + 1 
    return sequence

    while n >= 1:
        seq.append(n)
        if n % 3 == 0 and sequence[n] != sequence[n//3]: n = n // 3
        elif n % 2 == 0 and sequence[n] != sequence[n//2]: n = n // 2
        else: n = n-1
    seq.reverse(); return seq
```

Here is how it maps the minimum number for let's say n = 28,

```
n = 28
print(optimal_sequence(n))
>>> [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 5, 3, 4]
```

Now, if you can help me see if the code is right for the first part, if it is, then what is wrong with the second part of it beginning with while.
Thanks

Comment: hard to understand

Comment: Hold a paper and see what it does, thanks